# Round up an integer to decimal - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My issue is the following:

I have an integer -- e.g. `345` -- and I want to have a comma after the first number (`3,45`) and to be rounded up to 1 decimal place -- that is `3,5`.

How can I get this using SQL?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 4):

for example

```
select round(cast(345 as decimal)/100,1)
```

it's working in MySql, Postgresql, MS SQL

edit: in postgresql you can also

```
select round(345::decimal/100,1)
```

Comment: just perfect! this makes the job

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle:

```
SELECT ROUND(345/100, 1) FROM DUAL
```

If 345 is not a number but varchar2, use following code:

```
SELECT ROUND( TO_NUMBER(345)/100, 1) FROM DUAL
```